Should an Orthodox Jew give up on their dreams if their dream job involve the possibility of having to work on Shabbat?
If Judaism is a religion about living a fulfilling and meaningful life, then is following your dreams a Jewish value when it may conflict with Shabbat? For example, if someone’s dream is to be an airline pilot, but there is a chance that they will have to work on Shabbat, should they give up on their dreams? What I am trying to figure out is if following your dreams is a Jewish value or not. Is there some sort of special heter that can be given to someone to allow them to make their dream job work?

Breaking Shabbat is very serious. The Torah may care about a person having dreams, and consider it valuable for a person to follow them, but not at the expense of Shabbat. There are many inspiring stories of people who decided to pursue their dreams but not break Shabbat, such as the many immigrants to New York in the beginning of the last century taking their hand at the "American dream", and keeping Shabbat was very difficult, but saw blessings as a result.

Interesting question. Any profession could potentially involve being asked to work on Shabbat, so clearly you don't have to give up on that. When interviewing for a particular position, though, you are required to make it clear you're not working on Shabbat and refuse to take the job if that's not feasible

Following your dreams is not a tenet of Judaism. Observing Shabbat is.

I have heard of an American Orthodox Jewish airplane pilot fwiw

The Gemara says Hashem gives each person their dream job. So if you go with the shomer Shabbat job I’m sure it’ll work out just fine

@CuriousYid does it say this? I am familiar with the gemara that Hashem makes us like the job we have - are you referring to something else?

And Zack welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

@mbloch you’re right actually that’s what I’m referring to. The one on Brachot 43b

One thing worth pointing out in this connection: the Gemara tells us (Chullin 109b) that "everything that G-d prohibited to us, He permitted us something akin to it" (and gives a long list of examples). Here too, then: perhaps a person with such a dream could find a similar job where Shabbos is not an issue, such as a private-plane flight instructor.

I checked now. It is 43b you were right initially https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.43b.5
